# Camel sql component with cron

Tags: sql, cron, apache-camel

I am trying to set a scheduler in order to set a cron expression.

```
<camel:endpoint id="sqlEndpoint" uri="sql:${sqlQuery}?scheduler=spring&amp;scheduler.cron=0+6+8+*+*&amp;dataSourceRef=veloxityDS&amp;useIterator=false"/>
```

But when I run this as a consumer, this exception occured:

> org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateConsumerException: Failed to create
>   Consumer for endpoint: Endpoint[sql://$select * from
>   dual?dataSourceRef=veloxityDS&scheduler=spring&scheduler.cron=0+6+8++&useIterator=false].
>   Reason: There are 1 scheduler parameters that couldn't be set on the
>   endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that
>   they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{cron=0 6 8 *
>   *}]

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

The endpoint you are trying to create is using parameters that don't exist. There is a full list of parameters at: http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html

If you want your SQL procedure to run on a time interval you can either use a quartz endpoint, a polling consumer, or a route scheduler depending on your needs.

http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html

http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html

http://camel.apache.org/cronscheduledroutepolicy.html

Current parameter issues on your endpoint:

```
scheduler - not a supported parameter
scheduler.cron - not a supported parameter
dataSourceRef - deprecated.
```

Your scheduling alternatives leveraging only the sql endpoint are:

```
consumer.delay
consumer.initialDelay
consumer.useFixedDelay
maxMessagesPerPoll
```

Comment: Yes you can configure some polling features directly on the endpoint.  Your other option is to use route scheduling. http://camel.apache.org/cronscheduledroutepolicy.html

Comment: You are still using invalid parameters in your url.

Comment: to suggest scheduled Route policy to someone using A PollConsumer is just wrong. Please check it

Comment: You can complain all you like.  The problem is very simple.  Either use the supported SQL polling options or switch to a timer/cron endpoint for additional options.  My answer shows you all your choices

Comment: But you just can not use SqlConsumer with scheduled Route policy because when you start it with cron, SqlConsumer starts to poll every second after that and that can cause series problems like sql server exhaustion. Where do I know it? Because I did exactly like it and it Run exactly like it. And it is 4 am here , I needed to stop the jvm

Comment: You have your configurations setup incorrectly then.  You shouldn't be attempting to poll faster than your regular transaction speed.  You can use the scheduled route policy to stop the route and then turn it back on.  As long as you set your polling configuration to be longer than your worst case scenario delay your route can be stopped.  Then the scheduled route policy can start your route again.  If you aren't comfortable baking this all into one route you can use the control bus component.

Comment: Its a viable solution to your problem.